# Revolut: Someone transferred GBP into my Euro account on Revolut, will it turn up?

Tags: foreign-exchange, transfer

Someone  from Germany was sending me a transfer so I got the IBAN and BIC of my Euro account on revolut and sent it to them.  I have just checked their statement and it says they have sent GBP.  Will the funds be bounced back to them or will I get the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is - the money got bounced back to their account :(

Answer (score 1):

Your bank will convert it (taking a *fee* for that, of course). It might be delayed some days so it can clear (2-3 days).